# Hide fiberglass insulation in ceiling next to stone wall

Tags: walls, ceiling

I'm pretty inexperienced to say the least, so bear with me.

In my basement, the previous owners stuffed a bit of the pink insulation between the wall and ceiling but left it exposed.  I don't particularly want to install a proper ceiling down here since it's not living space, but I would like to cover up that insulation so it's not trying to fall down. Plus we'd like to use some of the space for gym equipment, and breathing that in seems less than ideal.

The difficult part (for me) is that the wall is a stone wall, so it's uneven.  What's the process for putting *something* up to hide and hold that insulation, but still fitting it as much to that wall as possible?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution here would be plywood. It would be easy to cut into the shapes you need (which are mostly rectangular) and then screw to the bottom of the joists. If you want to cover by the stones, consider caulk, but I think the plywood would suffice here.